# Python functions to find value of sin(x) and cos(x) from complex exponential

Tags: python

I was reading answers to different python questions on Stack-overflow. When I came across an answer, In the answer he used functions imag and real to find value of sinx and cosx like this

```
>>> e = 2.718281828459045
>>> X = 0.1
>>> (e**(X*1j)).imag   # sin(X)
0.09983341664682815
>>> (e**(X*1j)).real   # cos(X)
0.9950041652780258
```

so I was getting confused by functioning of imag and real.

Comment: "what does real function does here". I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean here

Comment: `real` and `imag` get the real and imaginary parts of the complex number that you have created

Comment: Actually this is a concept of Mathematics and not of python e raised to power (i*x) represents a complex number which can also be written as (cosx + i*sinx) where i=sqrt(-1).   (.imag) returns the imaginary part i.e sinx here and (.real) returns real part of the complex number i.e cosx here

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.real()` function return the real part of the complex argument.

```
Syntax: numpy.real(arr)

Parameters :
arr : [array_like] Input array.

Return : [ndarray or scalar] The real component of the complex argument. If val is real, the type of val is used for the output. If val has complex elements, the returned type is float.
```

Basic example:

```
import numpy as np
   
arr = np.array([1 + 3j, 5 + 7j, 9 + 11j])       
gfg = arr.real       
print (gfg)
```

Output :

```
[1. 5. 9.]
```

Thus, in your code, it is trying to find the imaginary and real part of the value.

Here is the in general mathematical formula `e^ix = cos(x)+isin(x)` of your code. Real is Cosx and Imaginary is sinx.